# Error setting keen.timestamp, value of property keen must be an object, is newtonsoft.json.linq.jproperty

Tags: analytics, keen-io

I'm using the Keen.IO .NET sdk and I can't seem to override the keen.timestamp property.  I keep receiving the error:

```
value of property keen must be an object, is newtonsoft.json.linq.jproperty"}
```

If I remove the keen property, then the event saves fine, but the keen.timestamp throws an error, if added.   The KeenClient.AddEvent() seems to check for a JObject but I'm not sure why JProperty is being found.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Here's my test code:

```
 var aEvent = new
    {
    keen = new[] { new { timestamp = "2000-05-30T12:12:12Z" } },
    username = user,
    position = i,
    event_id = "A123",
    score = new Random().Next(1, 11),
    demographics = new[] { new {gender = "M", city = "San Francisco", state = "CA"}}
    };
    keenClient.AddEvent("events_test", aEvent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `keen` property in the event is an `Object[]`, not just an `Object`. Try it just as an object and see if that works.

Comment: Using just an Object worked. Thanks!   Upadted line:  keen =  new { timestamp = "2000-05-30T12:12:12Z" },